# MongoDB Persistency when deploying to Kubernetes via VSCode Cloud Studio

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-code

I am trying to use VSCode Cloud Studio plugin to deploy and debug a project in Kubernetes. When I use intellij and Cloud Studio plugin there, everything works perfect. My MongoDB is persistent with each deployment. When I use VSCode and Cloud Studio there, MongoDB is not persistent anymore. I would appreciate any tips to make it work in VSCode too.

When I deploy via intellij it uses the same persistent volume claim. When I deploy via VSCode it creates a new persistent volume claim everytime.

Here is the launch.json for VSCode:

```
    {
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Kubernetes: Run/Debug",
            "type": "cloudcode.kubernetes",
            "request": "launch",
            "skaffoldConfig": "${workspaceFolder}\\skaffold.yaml",
            "watch": false,
            "cleanUp": false,
            "portForward": true,
            "imageRegistry": "XYZ",
            "debug": [
                {
                    "image": "XYZ",
                    "containerName": "XYZ",
                    "sourceFileMap": {
                        "${workspaceFolder}": "/root/"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the workspace.xml from intellij:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ChangeListManager">
    <list default="true" id="b5a077d4-323a-4042-8c4a-3bdd2d997e47" name="Changes" comment="" />
    <option name="SHOW_DIALOG" value="false" />
    <option name="HIGHLIGHT_CONFLICTS" value="true" />
    <option name="HIGHLIGHT_NON_ACTIVE_CHANGELIST" value="false" />
    <option name="LAST_RESOLUTION" value="IGNORE" />
  </component>
  <component name="Git.Settings">
    <option name="RECENT_GIT_ROOT_PATH" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
  </component>
  <component name="MarkdownSettingsMigration">
    <option name="stateVersion" value="1" />
  </component>
  <component name="ProjectId" id="2KV2OUqPUEf43q5Aj0UCGkKKm10" />
  <component name="ProjectViewState">
    <option name="hideEmptyMiddlePackages" value="true" />
    <option name="showLibraryContents" value="true" />
  </component>
  <component name="PropertiesComponent">
    <property name="RunOnceActivity.OpenProjectViewOnStart" value="true" />
    <property name="RunOnceActivity.ShowReadmeOnStart" value="true" />
    <property name="WebServerToolWindowFactoryState" value="false" />
    <property name="com.google.cloudcode.ide_session_index" value="20230118_0001" />
    <property name="last_opened_file_path" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
    <property name="nodejs_package_manager_path" value="npm" />
    <property name="settings.editor.selected.configurable" value="preferences.pluginManager" />
    <property name="ts.external.directory.path" value="C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\jsLanguageServicesImpl\external" />
  </component>
  <component name="RunDashboard">
    <option name="excludedTypes">
      <set>
        <option value="gcp-app-engine-local-run" />
      </set>
    </option>
  </component>
  <component name="RunManager">
    <configuration name="Develop on Kubernetes" type="google-container-tools-skaffold-run-config" factoryName="google-container-tools-skaffold-run-config-dev" show_console_on_std_err="false" show_console_on_std_out="false">
      <option name="allowRunningInParallel" value="false" />
      <option name="buildEnvironment" value="Local" />
      <option name="cleanupDeployments" value="false" />
      <option name="deployToCurrentContext" value="true" />
      <option name="deployToMinikube" value="false" />
      <option name="envVariables" />
      <option name="imageRepositoryOverride" />
      <option name="kubernetesContext" />
      <option name="mappings">
        <list />
      </option>
      <option name="moduleDeploymentType" value="DEPLOY_MODULE_SUBSET" />
      <option name="projectPathOnTarget" />
      <option name="resourceDeletionTimeoutMins" value="2" />
      <option name="selectedOptions">
        <list />
      </option>
      <option name="skaffoldConfigurationFilePath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/skaffold.yaml" />
      <option name="skaffoldModules">
        <list>
          <option value="XYZ" />
        </list>
      </option>
      <option name="skaffoldNamespace" />
      <option name="skaffoldProfile" />
      <option name="skaffoldWatchMode" value="ON_DEMAND" />
      <option name="statusCheck" value="true" />
      <option name="verbosity" value="WARN" />
      <method v="2" />
    </configuration>
  </component>
  <component name="SpellCheckerSettings" RuntimeDictionaries="0" Folders="0" CustomDictionaries="0" DefaultDictionary="application-level" UseSingleDictionary="true" transferred="true" />
  <component name="TaskManager">
    <task active="true" id="Default" summary="Default task">
      <changelist id="b5a077d4-323a-4042-8c4a-3bdd2d997e47" name="Changes" comment="" />
      <created>1674045398429</created>
      <option name="number" value="Default" />
      <option name="presentableId" value="Default" />
      <updated>1674045398429</updated>
      <workItem from="1674045401219" duration="2543000" />
    </task>
    <servers />
  </component>
  <component name="TypeScriptGeneratedFilesManager">
    <option name="version" value="3" />
  </component>
</project>
```

All other files are the same for the project of course.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Cloud Code for IntelliJ configuration is restricting the deployment to the XYZ module, but not in the Cloud Code for VS Code configuration.

Comment: Deployment of the app is fine. I see pods are getting recreated every time both via VSCode and intellij. Only difference is VSCode deletes the persistent volume claim that is connected to MongoDB and creates a new one (which causes the data loss in MongoDB) while intellij doesn't deletes the  persistent volume claim and still deploys the MongoDB. Behaviour of the intellij Cloud Code plugin is the one I expect (or want) to happen. Maybe I need to add some additional parameters to the launcher.json in VSCode for Cloud Code but I couldn't figure out what is causing the difference.

Comment: I suspect your PVC is installed from one of your other modules. On VSC because you’re not specifying a module, all modules are deployed and then deleted; on IJ only module XYZ is installed and deleted. It would help if you could provide a small example.